# Develop a Private package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Developing a flutter plugin which I want to share with my customer but I don't want to share my code logic. What should I do to achieve that?

The simple scenario is that my client will call the plugin and pass his parameters in it and then my plugin will return a value based on the values given.

i.e

```
input a = 2
input b = 4
output = 6
```

Here I am adding a + b but don't want to show my client a + b logic.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Create a backend API :)

Comment: @RustemKakimov This won't work because this will always require an internet connection.

Comment: You can make it difficult for people to read your code, but you can't hide it completely, since the client machine has to eventually read and execute something.

Comment: Probably create native frameworks or libraries and add a wrapper around it using dart. In that way, people will only see the wrapper implementation and you can hide the actual implementation